# pandas groupby().apply() grouping the same group again and again under different names

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas data from made up of various columns. Among them are 'branch' and 'barcode', by which I would like to group the dataframe and apply a function. Something I have done thousands of times before.

But this time it is showing behavior I've never seen before. Instead of sending each group to the function it sends the same group over and over. Only the name of the group changes as expected.

To showcase the problem, I'm printing out the group name (which contains the changing groupby keys) and the barcode and branch of the first row, which should be the same as the name but isn't.

Here's the basic code:

```
def main_features(df):
    print(df.name)
    print(df[['barcode', 'branch']].iloc[0])

df5 = df4.groupby(['branch', 'barcode']).apply(main_features)
```

Note the output:

```
(1, 90162800)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
(1, 38000232176)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 3, dtype: int64
(1, 38000232183)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 4, dtype: int64
(1, 3014260280772)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 18, dtype: int64
(1, 3014260289287)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 19, dtype: int64
(1, 4015400562818)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 44, dtype: int64
(1, 4015400563747)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 45, dtype: int64
(1, 4015400563846)
barcode    90162800
branch            1
Name: 46, dtype: int64
(1, 4015400564324)
...
...
...and so on
```

Note that the barcode and branch are changing in the df.name. But the actual branch and barcode are constant. Weirdest Pandas behavior ever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, though I really can't explain it.
At the end of my function, before I return the DF, I drop a column.
It's that drop column that seems to be causing all the funny behavior, though I"m sure I don't know why...

My function was...

```
def main_features(df):
    print(df.name)
    print(df[['barcode', 'branch']].iloc[0])
    ...
    ...
    ...
    **df = df.drop('temp_sales', axis=1)**
    return df
```

removing the drop method solved the problem